# Lazy<T> - Always create a new object?

Tags: c#

I am importing a `Lazy<MyForm>` object using MEF (dependency injection, constructor injection) and basically have the problem, that when I show and close the form and afterwards try to open the form again, it won't work anymore, cause the object has already been disposed. I want to have a completely new instance of the form everytime I open it.

Is there a class similar to `Lazy<T>`, but always gives me a new object?

**Edit:**

I can't give you my code at the moment, but I will go bit more into detail:

Where are two forms:

Form1 is the starting form, which has an ImportingConstructor which currently imports a `Lazy<Form2>` object.
My `Form2` has also an ImportingConstructor, which imports a few other classes.
When I click a button on `Form1`, `m_lazyForm2.Value` is being accessed and the `Form2` shows up.

MEF (and my Form1) are initialised using this bootstrapper I build myself.

```
internal class Bootstrapper<T> where T : Form
{
    [Import]
    private T m_frmStartup;
    private CompositionContainer m_container;

    public void Init()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("."));

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddPart(catalog);

        m_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        m_container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Application.Run(m_frmStartup);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just pass in a `Func<T>` that makes a new `T` every time?

Comment: My T classes have a ImportingConstructor aswell

Comment: Show code, how you set up your DI and how you are using it.

Comment: ExportFactory: Is that what I am looking for?

Comment: Not sure where your `Lazy<T>` comes into play in that code snippet.

Comment: Lazy<Form2> comes into play in the ImportingConstructor of Form1 for example. I don't want to always initialize Form2, when Form1 is being initialized, I want to lazy load, when a button is clicked and Form2 actually is about to be shown. Is it a bit better to understand now?

Comment: Actually I do think, ExportFactory is what I am looking for, I will test it out tommorow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as I stated in my comment already, I've found the solution myself.

The solution was to:

1. Change my `Lazy<T>` imports to `ExportFactory<T>` imports
2. Export all my Views with the `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]` attribute

This way, everytime you call `m_myViewExportFactory.CreateExport().Value`, it will give you a new instance of your view.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a [factory method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method), either passed to your form as delegate directly, or wrapped into a potentially anonymous implementation of some interface.

A [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) really only has the purpose to initialize some `T` at the last possible point in time, i.e. when it is really needed. To do so, it either simply invokes the default constructor for type `T` or it executes the supplied factory method in the form of a [`Func<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate.

You could just pass that `Func<T>` to your form instead of the `Lazy<T>` wrapper around it.